# Onchange event in Angular-Material Slider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I'm using slider provided by Angular-Material. I want to show a different control on selection of particular value in slider. How do I check if that value is selected in slider? 
E.g. If slider has three values VEG, NON-VEG and ALL and If user slides towards NON-VEG, then I want to show one more checkbox so how do I get NON-VEG is selected? so that I can show next control. 
My slider code looks like -

```
<div flex="60">
     <md-slider md-discrete ng-model="rating3" step="1" min="1" max="3" aria-label="rating" id="foodtype">           
  </div>
```

Any solution will be really helpful, thank you.

Comment: `ng-change` doesnt that work?

Comment: I am not sure what is the problem here. please update ur code at the following pen n ping back. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGbyJw

Comment: @ chandings I'm speechless! Thanks a bunch!, you saved my day!

Comment: @Kishor you need to play around with code more. The solution given by me is not ideal though it gets the work done. Also it is a good idea to post a working code.